# In Rails ERB view, how can I prevent underscore from being converted to hyphen?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Having the following code in an ERB view:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, id: 'stat', data: {_var_: '_foo_'}) %>
```

generates the following HTML:

```
<div id="stat" data--var-="_foo_">
</div>
```

My intention is to obtain

```
<div id="stat" data-_var_="_foo_">
</div>
```

i.e. I do not want

```
data--var-
```

but instead

```
data-_var_
```

How can I achieve this, please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed in the **ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper** [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag):

> To play nicely with JavaScript conventions **sub-attributes are
>   dasherized**. For example, a key *user_id* would render as *data-user-id*
>   and thus accessed as dataset.userId.

To illustrate, you can check in the **Rails source code** ([tag_helper.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1f38ef0c03cb218b5ab0c756477e1450d0e672c4/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb#L75)) `prefix_tag_option` invoking `key.to_s.dasherize`:

```
def content_tag(name, content_or_options_with_block = nil, options = nil, escape = true, &block)
    #...#
    content_tag_string(name, content_or_options_with_block, options, escape)
    #...#
end

def content_tag_string(name, content, options, escape = true)
    tag_options = tag_options(options, escape) if options
    #...#
end

def tag_options(options, escape = true)
    # ...
    # TAG_PREFIXES = ['aria', 'data', :aria, :data].to_set
    # invoke prefix_tag_option only if it's a data- sub-attributes 
    if TAG_PREFIXES.include?(key) && value.is_a?(Hash) 
        #...#
        output << prefix_tag_option(key, k, v, escape)
    end
    #...#
end


def prefix_tag_option(prefix, key, value, escape)
    key = "#{prefix}-#{key.to_s.dasherize}"
    #...#
end
```

If you don't want to *dasherize* your keys, a possible *"**workaround**"* is to set the `data-attribute` directly in the options hash, like this:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, "test", { id: 'stat', 'data-_var_': '_foo_' }) %>
```

This way, Rails will render:

```
<div id="stat" data-_var_="_foo_">test</div>
```

Comment: Kudos to @mrlew for a very detailed and didactic answer. Thank you !